# gae cloud sql active connections not closing (keeping the instance running)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I stopped all the instance Running in my app but still Cloud SQL have a one Active connection, I have no idea why.. is that keeping the Cloud Sql Instance running.. and I'm getting charged for the hours it used.. please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few places that a flag could be set to keep the Cloud SQL instance alive.

1. Go to the [Dev Console](https://console.developers.google.com) Your Project -> Cloud SQL -> SQL Instance -> Edit -> "Show advanced options..." -> ACTIVATION POLICY make sure its set to "On Demand".

if you are still seeing it up then:

2. [Go here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/admin-api/v1beta3/instances/get#try-it) and fill out the information. Under fields select only 'settings' click execute and scroll down. Look for 'activationPolicy' and see whats set to. You can use the API browser to change the setting or [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/)

Comment: There are new updates on cloud console and I can't figure out how but also I have the similar issue there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74496090/deleted-cloud-sql-instance-and-still-get-charged Please help