# Deleted Cloud SQL instance and still get charged

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have my google cloud project which is the firebase project where I created years ago `2018` then four days ago `Nov 15, 2022` I created the `Cloud SQL Instance` Into the same project and after that it only took 48 hours where I saw the billing goes from `$0.xx` to `$13.xx` in just one day. So I decided to stop that Cloud SQL instance and even I deleted it. After few hours the billing goes back to `$0.xx`. But after 72 hours (yesterday) I go back to the cloud console and I saw the billing goes up to `$31.21` where from firebase console it shows `$0.08` for firebase services and `$31.13` for non-firebase services as you can see the following screenshot here:

[image: firebase monthly usage]

So I did go back to the cloud console into the billing section at the reports section where there's a table that shows SKU and its usage as the following screenshot:

[image]

And billing overview screenshot:

[image]

As you can see there, it seems the Cloud SQL services are still running and I got charged from it, and I am sure that I deleted the Cloud SQL instance only after 48 hours, I even recheck many times on SQL tab to see if there's any instance going on but no instance at all.

Please help me understand the situation here and figure out what went wrong here. Thanks.

Comment: This is expected. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/70789502/12265927

Comment: Mussa Charles, was the above link provided helpful for your issue?